# Retreive specific data to detailview via ajax calender'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, ajax

i have a database in mysql that uses timestamp, but in my asp.net , i want to retrieve a specific data while selecting the date (ajax calender), but when i select the specific date, the data wont show in my detailsview.

i tried using control parameters and it doesnt work.
Is there a way to convert mysql timestamp to string in anyway?
I didnt use any code behind at all.